# FIFO implementing system of processes

Tags: c, process, fifo

I am trying to learn processes in C and I thiiink I understood the logic of pipe, but can't understand fifo, even if I read a lot about it. I recently made a program using pipe that takes a string from standard input, writes it in pipe1, checks if it's alphanumeric and if so, pipe3 reads it and shows it. If the string only contains digits, pipe2 reads it and replaces digits with _, then pipe4 reads the new string and shows it. 
I'm putting it here, because I want to make something similar using fifo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
int p1[2];
int p2[2];
int p3[2];
int p4[2];

char input_str[100];
pid_t fork1;
pid_t fork2;

if (pipe(p1)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
    return 1;
}
if (pipe(p2)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
    return 1;
}
if (pipe(p3)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
    return 1;
}
if (pipe(p4)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
    return 1;
}


scanf("%s", input_str);

int isAlpha = 0; 
int onlyDigits = 0; 
for (int i=0; input_str[i]!= '\0'; i++) 
{

    if (isalpha(input_str[i]) != 0) {
        isAlpha = 1;
        onlyDigits = 0;
    }
    else if (isdigit(input_str[i]) != 0) {
        isAlpha = 1;
        onlyDigits = 1;
    }
    else { 
        isAlpha = 0;
        onlyDigits = 0;
    }
}


fork1 = fork();
if (fork1 < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed" );
    return 1;
}


else if (fork1 > 0)
{
    close(p1[0]); 
    write(p1[1], input_str, strlen(input_str)+1);
}


else
{
    close(p1[1]);
    char string_from_p1[100];
    read(p1[0], string_from_p1, 100);
    close(p1[0]);
    fork2 = fork();
    if (onlyDigits) {
        for (int i=0; string_from_p1[i]!= '\0'; i++) {
            if (isdigit(string_from_p1[i]) != 0)
                string_from_p1[i] = '_';
        }
        write(p2[1], string_from_p1, strlen(string_from_p1)+1);
    }
    else if (isAlpha) {
        write(p3[1], string_from_p1, strlen(string_from_p1)+1);
    }
    if (fork2 < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed" );
            return 1;
    }
    else if (fork2 > 0) {
        char string_from_p2[100];
        char string_from_p3[100];
        char string_from_p4[100];
        if (onlyDigits) {
            close(p2[1]);
            read(p2[0], string_from_p2, 100);
            close(p2[0]);
            write(p4[1], string_from_p2, strlen(string_from_p2)+1);
            close(p4[1]);
            read(p4[0], string_from_p4, 100);
            printf("String from pipe4: %s\n", string_from_p4);
        }
        else if (isAlpha) {
            close(p3[1]);
            read(p3[0], string_from_p3, 100);
            printf("String from pipe3: %s\n", string_from_p3);
        }
    }
exit(0);
}
}
```

Not sure how correct that is, but the FIFO program will only have 3 processes, it first reads from standard input lines of max 30 characters, writes in first exit (process2) the digits and in second exit (process3) the letters. then in process2 only shows the result (digits found), and in process3 turns small letters into capital letters and shows the result.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: @4386427 Fifo, also known as a named pipe, is an OS abstraction, not a data type. The C language _does_ provide an interface to fifos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point you could try something like this (most of the functions needs still to be implemented, see comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void read_and_write(const char *digits_fifo, const char *chars_fifo);
pid_t spawn_digits_child(const char *digits_fifo);
pid_t spawn_chars_child(const char *chars_fifo);
void digits_child(const char *digits_fifo);
void chars_child(const char *chars_fifo);
void wait_until_children_finish(pid_t pid1, pid_t pid2);

#define MAX_INPUT 30

int main() {
    char *digits_fifo = "/tmp/digits_fifo";
    char *chars_fifo = "/tmp/chars_fifo";

    mkfifo(digits_fifo, 0666);
    mkfifo(chars_fifo, 0666);

    //fork digits process
    pid_t pid_digits = spawn_digits_child(digits_fifo);

    //fork chars process
    pid_t pid_chars = spawn_chars_child(chars_fifo);

    //parent
    read_and_write(digits_fifo, chars_fifo);
    wait_until_children_finish(pid_digits, pid_chars);
    exit(0);
}

pid_t spawn_digits_child(const char *digits_fifo) {
    pid_t pid1;
    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error digits process\n");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid1 == 0) {
        digits_child(digits_fifo);
        exit(0);
    }
    return pid1;
}

pid_t spawn_chars_child(const char *chars_fifo) {
    //do sth similar then in spawn_digits_child but for chars child process
}

void wait_until_children_finish(pid_t pid1, pid_t pid2) {
    //use waitpid to wait for child process termination
}

void read_and_write(const char *digits_fifo, const char *chars_fifo) {
    //read input string 
    //open the two named pipes with O_WRONLY
    //check with isdigit respective isalpha and send to the corresponding named pipe
    //don't forget to close file handles
}

void chars_child(const char *chars_fifo) {
    //open named piped with O_RDONLY
    //e.g. int chars_fd = open(chars_fifo, O_RDONLY);
    //read from pipe
    //do uppercase string
    //output it with printf
}

void digits_child(const char *digits_fifo) {
    //open named piped with O_RDONLY
    //e.g. int chars_fd = open(digits_fifo, O_RDONLY);
    //read from pipe
    //output it with printf
}
```